# Why can't I use a private,internal,fileprivate method within a class/static method?

Tags: swift

Assuming that there are two classes

File A:

```
import Foundation
class ClassA {
    /// a method that I don't want to exposed to others
    static func privateMethod(append aStirng:String) -> String {
        return  "Appended String:" + aStirng
    }

    static func classMethod() -> String {
        let theString = privateMethod(append: "random string") //problematic line when privateMethod(append:) is declared as private,fileprivate,internal...
        return theString
    }
}
```

File B:

```
import Foundation
class ClassB {
   func aMethod() {
      print(ClassA.classMethod())
   }
}
```

This works. but I don't want ClassB to use `privateMethod(append:)` like `ClassA.privateMethod(append: "")`. So I marked the method with `private`,`internal`,`fileprivate` but none of these worked.

[image]

Why is it so? and how can I hide a method from ClassB?

[EDIT] It does not matter whether the two classes are split to separate files or merged to one file. an error still occurs

Comment: @Hamish yes i get a compiler error.  i added the image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing an error because the `privateMethod` in your screenshot is not a static method.

Static methods cannot call instance (non-static) methods of the class.

`privateMethod` is static in your initial example code though? Changing *ClassA* to this should work, while keeping the private method hidden from *ClassB*:

```
class ClassA {
    private static func privateMethod(append aString: String) -> String {
        return  "Appended String:" + aString
    }

    static func classMethod() -> String {
        let theString = privateMethod(append: "random string")
        return theString
    }
}
```

Comment: two prefixes.. that's something i never expected. weird but it works! thanks